# Handling *other* attributes in a drag'n'drop form

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, vector-layer

I built a form for my vector layer using the Drag'n'drop form designer but I only did so for some of the layers fields.

Is it possible to automatically add widgets for the *other* fields to the form, e.g. in a separate tab without writing custom Python init code? For example for a text field a text input (~`QLineEdit`), for a integer input an integer numeric input (~`QSpinBox`). If so, how?

E.g. if my layer has the fields:

- foo
- bar
- baz

and I used drag'n'drop to add the following fields to my form:

- foo
- bar

I would like to have QGIS automatically use its default widget magic for the remaining field:

- baz

Answer (score 1):

If by "default widget magic" you mean using a default value expression, this does still work even if a field isn't added to the form via drag and drop designer.

Comment: I mean an appropriate widget in the form for the user to see and edit the attributes' values with.